# tvOS game launch image shows on simulator but not on device

Tags: spritekit, xcode, swift, apple-tv

I’ve set up a launch image in XCode and it does show up in the simulator, but on the Apple TV it just displays a blurry gray background. The image is the correct size and doesn’t have any transparency.

I have tried full clean and delete the app from the device – neither has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple deletes from the device, clean and device and XCode restarts, it magically started working, though not always 100% reliably. Seems to be "one of those things".

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting an answer to this issue :)

Comment: If you find the exact order of operations that works 100% please post it and add the particular tvOS version. The OS probably uses both an on-storage cache (for quick display on launch) and in-memory cache (running OS) and either of those being stale will cause the image to not get updated.